# `tmux attach` fails to find the active session

Tags: tmux

I know I have 2 sessions running, I deactivated by [bind]+d. Now I try `tmux attach` and it says `no current session`.

Just in case it's failing to attach the session in a weird way, I try `tmux list-sessions`, and it says `no server running on /private/tmp/tmux-501/default`, which exists and is in fact size 0. Are my sessions just gone drastically, or is it looking in the wrong place? I launch `htop` and I can see my tmux processes, one has been running for a long time.

I'm on OS X 10.11.16, tmux 2.3.

Comment: Did you update tmux recently?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I hadn't updated tmux while it was running, though tbh I can't remember exactly the last time I did a brew update

Answer (score 0):

you can use this plugin [tmux-resurrect](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-resurrect). then

`prefix + Ctrl-s` - save

`prefix + Ctrl-r` - restore

also I recommend
[.tmux](https://github.com/gpakosz/.tmux)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to remember this for future ref